# Error TS2305 y TS2307

Tags: angular, typescript

estoy realizando un proyecto en angular y me aparece el siguiente error en la consola al ejecutar `ng serve`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Ya actualice el typescript y node
- Ya importe "map" y "observable" en el app.module
- El "map" esta importado desde "rxjs"
- Cuando accedo desde el navegador con "localhost:4200" me aparece un mensaje con `cannon get /`

Comment: ¿Podrías sustituir la imagen por el texto, copiado de la consola? apenas puedo leer nada ahí

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando Angular 6+, con RxJS 6, los imports cambian. La nueva forma es:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Y tendrían que estar en el componente o servicio en que los uses, no en `app.module.ts`.

---

Edit: lo siguiente también solucionaría el problema:

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Pero esto añade nuevas dependencias, por lo que cambiar los imports es más recomendable.